# It is possible with JQuery to get the ID of an img.show()?

Tags: jquery, attributes, jquery-selectors

I know it's possible to get the ID with this :

```
      $('div#test img').attr('id')
```

But i want more ! Only get the ID when my img have the ".show()" :
Only one image in my div have ".show()" others images are with ".hide()".

Thanks for answers guys !

Comment: you could probably get all the ID using var img = document.getElementById('myImageId'); and then show and hide each image as you wish     img.style.visibility = 'visible';

Answer (score 1):

So use [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

```
$('div#test img:visible').attr('id')
```